# Home work problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the number of triplets satisfying the following equation :

x raised to power 4 + y raised to power 4 + z raised to power 4 + 1 = 4xyz

Comment: I'm not sure this is an algebraic number theory question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** By AM-GM you have 
$$\frac{x^4+y^4+z^4+1} 4 \geq \sqrt[4]{x^4y^4z^4}=|xyz|$$

Comment: Can you please really get me to the solution. It would be very nice of you. Thank you